# Is there any significant benefit in adding multi-column indices in MySQL over having single column indices?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

Being pretty new to database optimization in systems with high load I have the following question - lets assume we have the following query (query is with sample data):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ticket 
WHERE ticket_status='draft' 
AND user_id='789437879' 
ORDER BY ticket_id DESC  LIMIT 0, 15
```

We already have the following indizes:

```
CREATE INDEX ticket_status on ticket(ticket_status);
CREATE INDEX user_id on ticket(user_id);
CREATE INDEX ticket_id on ticket(ticket_id);
```

Would there be a significant performance benefit for optimizing this query if we do the following:

```
CREATE INDEX make_that_query_more_efficient on ticket(user_id,ticket_status);
```

Or does it make barely any difference as all the columns are indexed anyways?

Comment: How many tickets do a user_id have?

Comment: Could be one but could also be thousands.

Comment: I'd guess the composite index will give a minor improvement. But why don't you create the index and see what happens performance-wise.

Comment: @jarlh Because Production deployment is a highly sensitive task in that project which is growing heavily 24/7. Creating a useless index which is causing the INSERTs to be slower would be a problem, I have to know what I do before I deploy ;)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Hi @Blackbam, can you please capture and upload explain plan for that query? Let's see how DB handles it.

Comment: I don't think there will be a noticeable improvement unless your select only selects those two columns.

Comment: One table copy may use only one index. You may create indices by each separate column - but only one of them may be used. *Would there be a significant performance benefit for optimizing this query if we do the following* Maybe with high probability. Test also the index by `(user_id, ticket_status, ticket_id)`.

Comment: The problem with this question is that we can't tell you in advance whether you will get  significant performance gain from using a multi-column index! It depends on your data (how selective is the additional column in the index and how many records remain to be sorted by the 3rd column). The word significant is also fuzzy, what we may consider significant, you may not consider significant. The best way for you is to test it: get similar size and characteristic data into your dev environment and test the performance with single column indexes and multi-column index and you will know the answer

Comment: Please read Marcus Windand's https://use-the-index-luke.com/ .

Comment: @O.Jones Looks good, I will read it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the query.  But definitely in your example.

In many queries, it makes a huge difference.

Here is one discussion on such: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1 . It discusses various indexing strategies on a simple query.  The conclusion is that a composite index is clearly optimal for the query.

Meanwhile, there are dozens, maybe hundreds, of examples in this forum where my solution to a performance problem (high CPU, slow query, etc) is primarily to replace a single-column index with a multi-column index.  The performance gain is sometimes spectacular when `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, *and* `LIMIT` can all be handled by the `INDEX`.

A many-to-many mapping table ('junction') is a very common schema pattern that novices fail to index properly.  More on it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

For your query, this would make a world of difference:

```
INDEX(user_id, ticket_status,  -- these two can be in either order
      ticket_id)               -- this needs to be last
```

The execution will quickly drill into the Index's BTree to the row(s) with `ticket_status='draft' AND user_id='789437879'`.  It will start at the end of such items and scan backward (`DESC`), picking up 15 (or fewer) items.  Then it will look up the other columns (`*`) and deliver them.

Almost any other index would require scanning more than just 15 items.

As for your indexes.

- If `ticket_id` is already the `PRIMARY KEY`, do *not* add `INDEX(ticket_id)`; it will be useless.
- If any of your indexes is a prefix of the index I recommend, DROP it; it will be redundant and in the way.  (Use `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see this.)
- If the Optimizer picked your `(ticket_status)`, it would look at all the entries with desired status, filter based on `user_id`, sort the results, then peel off 15 rows.
- Similarly for `(user_id)`
- If the Optimizer were to use `INDEX(ticket_id)`, it would start at the end of the ids and work backward.  If there were not 15 relevant rows, it would not stop until it scanned the entire table.
- Note that my composite index even avoids the sort.
- The rest of the indexes may or may not be useful; it depends on whether other queries can use them.
- A suitable index is likely to be much more beneficial to a `SELECT` than a burden on `INSERTs`; so don't worry about this tradeoff.
- Starting with `user_id` may be useful to other queries; starting with `status` seems less likely.  The single-column `INDEX(ticket_status)` is unlikely to be used by any query due to "cardinality".
- My 3-column index is likely to be much better than your similar 2-column index.  Mine takes care of the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT`; yours needs to gather lots of rows and sort them.
- If there are big `TEXT` columns in the `*`, the performance difference may be more dramatic.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. In practice for this query it turned out that adding the composite index made a significant difference for that certain query.